# REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL: How to perform regular expression matching on multiple columns

Tags: apache-pig

I am trying to perform regular expression matching on multiple columns.

Here's the sample data :

> (dev=03,user=000,intip=138.40.13.24,extip=198.167.0.194,src_port=1109,dest_port=2613,response=6)
>   (dev=03,user=000,intip=148.12.16.78,extip=168.67.0.10,src_port=1460,dest_port=3610,response=6)

Expected output:

> (03,000,138.40.13.24,198.167.0.194,1109,2613,6)
>
> (03,000,148.12.16.78,168.67.0.10,1460,3610,6)

Here's the script:

```
A = LOAD '---' using PigStorage as (value: chararray);

B = foreach A generate REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL('value', '(^.=(.)$)');

dump B;
```

Output: Blank

> ()
>
> ()
>
> ()

If i will perform regular expression matching on single column using script :

```
A = LOAD '---' using PigStorage as (dev: chararray, user:chararray, intip:chararray, extip:chararray, srcport:chararray, destport:chararray, response:chararray);

B = foreach A generate REGEX_EXTRACT(dev, '(^.=(.)$)');

dump B;
```

Output:

> (03) (03)

Can anyone please let me know, any mistake in my `REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL` ?

Looking forward to reply, your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you have `value` in quotes in your first script?

Comment: Built in function [REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.1/func.html#regex-extract) syntax. Regular expression for multiple columns or complete text declared in quotes.

Comment: @ManishV That means that `'value'` is being treated like the literal string value, if you remove the quotes it will use the value stored in `value`.

Comment: We stored all the sample data into Value fields as chararray and applied REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL. As specified in Syntax [REGEX](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.1/func.html#regex-extract) REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL('192.168.1.5:8020', '(.*)\:(.*)'); thats why i added quotes.

Comment: @ManishV In the example it is using the quotes because 192.168.1.5:8020 is a literal string.  value is not a literal string, it is the name of a variable in the schema. In order to access the data assigned to `value` you need to not use quotes.

Comment: @mr2ert Thanks for suggestion. I tried REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(value, '(^.=(.)$)'); without quotes also but still got blank result. As i got feedback from my another post REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL not works with multiple columns, we need to extract each columns.

Comment: @ManishV That is because your regular expression in REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL doesn't match on the given input.

Answer (score 1):

old thread but I ran into it having the same problem so it might help others

Starting from the first script and assuming your sample data is not a pig tuple but the raw input :

1. PigStorage splits into fields base on one-char separator, you have comma and parenthesis to deal with so use TextLoader instead
2. you pattern doesn't match. It should be something describing all line, parenthesis "grouping" what you want to catch
3. FLATTEN allows to create a tuple out of your REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL

So :

```
A = LOAD 'stack' using TextLoader as (line:chararray);

B = FOREACH A GENERATE FLATTEN(REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(line, '^\\(dev=(\\d{2}),user=(\\d{3}),intip=(\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}),extip=(\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}),src_port=(\\d{1,5}),dest_port=(\\d{1,5}),response=(\\d{1})\\)$'));

dump B
```

output is

(03,000,138.40.13.24,198.167.0.194,1109,2613,6)

(03,000,148.12.16.78,168.67.0.10,1460,3610,6)

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue and found the Pig Documentation to be confusing. So here is what I found out:
REGEX_EXTRACT and REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL have very different matching behavior.

```
REGEX_EXTRACT(chararray source, chararray regex, int n)
```

searches occurances of 'regex' anywhere in 'source'. 'regex' need not contain any '()' for generating output. 'regex' need not match the entire 'source'.

```
REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(chararray source, chararray regex)
```

will only have a match if 'regex' matches the entire 'source'. Contrary to what the documentation will make you believe, REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL do not repeatedly match 'regex' on the 'source' and return all of those matches as tuples. It will not return anything if 'regex' do not contain '()'. The number of elements returned in the tuple is the number of top level '()'.

So for:

```
(dev=03,user=000,intip=138.40.13.24,extip=198.167.0.194,src_port=1109,dest_port=2613,response=6) 

REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(line, '(\\d+)')
```

Will not match anything.

```
REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(line, '\\(dev=(\\d+).*')
```

Will return (03).